# Is there any event which get triggered when an item is added to SfDataGrid in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, sfdatagrid

I have a `SfDataGrid` in my `Xamarin` code base and in that `SfDataGrid`, there is an `Entry` for each row. I have to set `Focus` to the `Entry` when I add an item. I add Items to the SfDataGrid via a popup.
So, are there any events exists to do that? if so, what would be the best way to implement that feature?

```
<SfDataGrid
 SwipeEnded="DataGrid_SwipeEnded">
     <SfDataGrid.Columns>
          <GridTemplateColumn> 
               <GridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
               </GridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
               <GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <CustomEntry
                       BindingContextChanged="Entry_ContextChanged"
                       Focused="Entry_Focused">
                         </CustomEntry>
                    </DataTemplate>
               </GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridTemplateColumn>
     </SfDataGrid.Columns>
</SfDataGrid>
```

Comment: If you are adding via a popup, shouldn’t you already know when an item is being added?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I know. The popup sets the values of the item. and the ViewModel of the page where SfDataGrid situated adds the Item.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the official document about the sfdatagrid? In the official document, there are all the events can be triggered in the sfdatagrid.

And there is a value changed event seems can meet your requirement:

The SfDataGrid.ValueChanged event will be triggered whenever the current cell’s value has been changed in the GridTextColumn, GridNumericColumn or GridSwitchColumn. This event handler contains the parameter of type ValueChangedEventArgs that contains the following properties.

1. CellValue : The initial value when current cell entered edit mode.
2. Column : Gets the current GridColumn that contains the grid cell for which value is edited or changed.
3. NewValue : The newly edited value to be committed.
4. RowColumnIndex : The current RowColumnIndex of the grid cell undergoing the value change.
5. RowData : The RowData of the row that contains the grid cell undergoing the value change.

For more information, you can check the [official document](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/grid-events#valuechanged-event).

Comment: Appreciate your effort! It didn't work for me. I have updated the question by including the implementation of my DataGrid.

Comment: But the other events in the official document can't work either. It doesn't have a event about item adding. @ZamrinJameel

Comment: I Omitted all the events when I post the code. now, I have added the events I'm using @Liyun Zhang

Comment: The events sfdatagrid has can't meet your requirement, you may need to set the focused when you add the item by yourself. @ZamrinJameel

Comment: Ok I'll have a look. Thank you!